# How to predict Mersenne Twister patterns after more than 625 interation?

Tags: python, random

I read the [Wikipedia article for Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister), in which it mentioned:

> The algorithm in its native form is not suitable for cryptography (i.e. it is not a CSPRNG). The reason is that observing a sufficient number of iterations (624 in the case of MT19937, since this is the size of the state vector from which future iterations are produced) allows one to predict all future iterations.

So I thought given a particular seed, after 625 iterations I'll see the return value start repeat. And I did these code:

```
random.seed( 10 )
for i in xrange(10000):
    n = random.random()
    if n not in L:
        L.append(n)
```

And I did `len(L)`, I was shocked, it is `10000`, they are all different values! Then I thought some values may be close to others. And I did:

```
for i in L:
    if abs(i-L[0]) <= 0.00001:
        print L.index(i)
```

I got `0`, which means no numbers are close to the first number of the list.

Through `random.getstate()`, I can get a tuple, its second element is another tuple which contains 625 `long` digits, I thought it was related to the pattern stuff. But don't know how. Then, How should I to predict the behaviour of Python `random.random()` for a particular seed?

Comment: You should read that quote more carefully; it says that you can *predict* future iterations, not that you've *seen* them all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what does predict mean here?

Comment: ...what it means everywhere; to foretell based on present knowledge

Comment: @jonrsharpe, so is it able to predict the exact number of the next random? Or lock it in a small range of list?

Comment: You can build a mathematical model which, given 624 sequential values, will tell you what the 625th will be. In fact, the previous 624 values can be used to seed the RNG, bringing it to the desired state.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo, should these 624 values be the values in my `L`, or in random.getstate()[1]?